# Error al seleccionar una variable

Tags: r

A partir de un archivo vcf:

```
       Amaranthus_sp <- fread("variants_Amaranthus_sp.vcf")
```

Intento seleccionar aquellos valores que tienen una ","

```
   "#CHROM"           "POS"  "ID"   "REF" "ALT"    "QUAL"             
M3V_32_Cucumis_melo    1       .       T    <*>      0
M3V_32_Cucumis_melo    2       .       C    T,<*>    0
M3V_32_Cucumis_melo    3       .       A    <*>      0
M3V_32_Cucumis_melo    4       .       G    C,<*>    0
M3V_32_Cucumis_melo    5       .       C    <*>      0
M3V_32_Cucumis_melo    6       .       T    A,<*>    0
```

Intento selecionar aquellos valores del dataframe que tengan una , en REF para obtener algo así:

```
   "#CHROM"           "POS"  "ID"   "REF" "ALT"    "QUAL"             
M3V_32_Cucumis_melo    2       .       C    T,<*>    0
M3V_32_Cucumis_melo    4       .       G    C,<*>    0
M3V_32_Cucumis_melo    6       .       T    A,<*>    0
```

Para ello ejecuto los siguientes comandos:

```
 Amaranthus_sp<-Amaranthus_sp[which(Amaranthus_sp$ALT == ","),]];dim(Amaranthus_sp)
```

y me aparece una tabla vacía.

En cambio cuando ejecuto este comando:

```
 Amaranthus_sp<-Amaranthus_sp[which(Amaranthus_sp$ALT == "<*>"),];dim(Amaranthus_sp)
```

Selecciona aquellas filas que no tiene , en esa columna.

Además el tipo de mi columna es:

```
     class(Amaranthus_sp$ALT)
      [1] "character"
```

No se cual es mi error.

Gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**La función grepl**

```
Amaranthus_sp<-Amaranthus_sp[grepl(",",Amaranthus_sp$ALT),]
```

El primer argumento de esta función es  la cadena buscada y el segundo es la cadena de texto donde buscar. Devuelve TRUE si se encuentra el valor buscado y FALSE de otro modo.

Seguramente hay otras soluciones. Por ejemplo el **Tidyverse** probé la función `stringr::str_detect`.

***¿Cuál es tu error?***

Estas usando de una manera inadecuada la función `==`, esta devuelve verdadero cuando los valores son exactamente iguales. Cuando usas `Amaranthus_sp$ALT == "<*>"` devuelve lo que esperas porque los valores en ALT son exactamente `"<*>"`. Sin embargo cuando haces `Amaranthus_sp$ALT == ","` los valores en ALT no son exactamente `","` sino que son del tipo `C,<*>`.

También podrías omitir el uso de `which`. Cuando trabajas con data.frame y haces un filtro del tipo `df[v,]` `v` puede ser un vector numérico, cuyas entradas son el número de las filas que deseas  mantener luego del filtro. Pero `v` tambien puede ser un vector de valores lógicos cuya longitud es igual al numero de filas en `df` en este caso el filtro devolverá aquellas filas en donde `v` seas "TRUE". Como `Amaranthus_sp$ALT == "<*>` nos devuelve un vector de valores lógicos de longitud igual al número de filas en `Amaranthus_sp` entonces estamos en el segundo caso y podemos omitir el `which`.

Comment: Cuando aplico la función: grepl me sale el siguiente error: Warning message: In grepl(Todos$ALT, ",") :  argument 'pattern' has length > 1 and only the first element will be used. En cambio he usado la segunda alternativa que me distes creando una columna a la derecha de la tabla: Amaranthus_sp$is_alt<-str_detect(Amaranthus_sp$ALT, ",");dim(Amaranthus_sp) y posteriormente seleccionando aquellas filas con valor true. Muchas gracias por la explicación y soluciones.

Comment: Tienes razón, había intercambiado los argumentos de grepl ya lo corregir.