# ¿Cómo separar una cadena a partir de una condición?

Tags: r

Tengo una columna de un dataframe en R en la que los valores son de este tipo:

```
WRL. ARMT 265/65R17 112H SL  
WRL. ARMT 255/65R17 110T  
WRL. SUV 235/60R18 103V
```

y necesito quedarme solo con el, por ejemplo, `265/65R17` en una nueva columna y no se como hacerlo

lo unico que logre fue separarlo con `strsplit` pero me quedo algo asi como:

```
c("WRL.", "ARMT", "255/65R17", "110T")
```

y no se como quedarme solo con la tercer posicion, ademas no siempre que haga eso queda en la tercer posicion, a veces puede quedar en la cuarta como aqui

```
c("F1", "ASYMETRIC", "3", "255/35R18", "94Y")
```

Comment: Bienvenido a stackoverflow. Te invito a leer [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) y de paso revisar el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para futuras preguntas que realices. Creo que deberías de indicar todas las formas posibles en las que la información se puede presentar ya que muy probablemente la solución sería un algoritmo.

Comment: ¿Has probado después del SPLIT iterar sobre los resultados y extraer aquel resultado que contenga una "/"? Podrías hacer uso de una expresión regular.

Comment: No lo probe pero creo que es una solucion, seria preguntar sobre el strsplit con un IF si contiene "/" ELSE que me devuelva toda la expresion?

Comment: El algoritmo examinaría los resultados de cada split, por ejemplo ("F1", "ASYMETRIC", "3", "255/35R18", "94Y"). Primero revisaría "F1" y buscaria una "/" como no existe, examina el siguiente elemento "ASYMETRIC" y así sucesivamente hasta que se encontrara con "255/35R18" que sí contiene una "/" en cuyo caso regresaría ese valor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Otra alternativa es usar expresiones regulares para capturar el patrón que nos interesa de la cadena completa. En tu caso el patrón de interés pareciera ser algo así `[número]/[número][caracter][número]`. puedes usar [`strcapture()`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/utils/versions/3.6.1/topics/strcapture) que es una función base de R para hacer algo así:

```
strcapture('(\\d*[/]\\d*.\\d*)', df$texto, data.frame(valor=character()))

      valor
1 265/65R17
2 255/65R17
3 235/60R18
```

El primer parámetro es la expresión regular correspondiente al patrón de captura, el segundo es el vector de entrada, y el último representa el prototipo de como queremos los datos capturados.

Answer (score 1):

Estas en buen camino.

La función `strsplit`, regresa una lista por lo que podemos combinarla `unlist`, si suponemos que en cada fila aparece solo una vez `"/"`(Tomando la idea de @Carlos Pozo). Podemos quedarnos con la cadena de caracteres que contenga `"/"` con la función `grepl` (en esta [pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/277197/error-al-seleccionar-una-variable/277259#277259) más detalles sobre `grepl`).

Con lo anterior el siguiente código logra lo que necesitas:

```
#Leemos los datos
df<-data.frame(texto=c(
                 "WRL. ARMT 265/65R17 112H SL",  
               "WRL. ARMT 255/65R17 110T", 
               "WRL. f SUV 235/60R18 103V"),stringsAsFactors = F)

#Creamos una nueva columna con el fracmento de texto que se requiere
df$nueva_col<-
unlist(strsplit(df$texto," "))[grepl("/",unlist(strsplit(df$texto," ")))]

#Resultados
df

                        texto nueva_col
1 WRL. ARMT 265/65R17 112H SL 265/65R17
2    WRL. ARMT 255/65R17 110T 255/65R17
3   WRL. f SUV 235/60R18 103V 235/60R18
```

Comment: esto funciona perfecto, el unico problema es que hay filas donde ` "/" ` esta dos veces que voy a ver si las puedo descartar antes, gracias!

Comment: Como es el formato de texto cuando ` "/" ` aparece 2 veces?